# put comma in alexa rank

Tags: php

I have alexa function and return alexa rank. I want to put comma in every three digit.

ex: 1,500,500

I have tried to use number_format() but it doesn't work with me. here is the function

```
<?php
/**
 * Get Popularity Text of a Domain via Alexa XML Data
 *
 * @return string|FALSE text or FALSE on error
 */
function alexa_get_rank($domain)
{
    $alexa = "http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=s&url=%s";
    $request_url =  sprintf($alexa, urlencode($domain));


    $xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url);
    if (!$xml) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    $nodeAttributes = $xml->SD[1]->POPULARITY->attributes();
    $text = (int) $nodeAttributes['TEXT'];

    $num = number_format($text);

    return $num;
}
```

this only returns 3 numbers

ex: ranks is 1,500,500 but it shows 500 only.

thank you

Comment: What does `var_dump($text);` give you?

Comment: This function works fine for me. Where are you outputting `$num`?

Comment: When I set `$text` to be 5000000. I get exactly what you want with `number_format`. When I use 500.00, I get 500. Are you sure you're not misreading the actual value as something it isn't?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could always run a simple while statement::

```
$text = (int) $nodeAttributes['TEXT'];
while (true){
    $num = preg_replace('/(-?\d+)(\d\d\d)/', '$1,$2', $text );
    if ($num != $text ) {
        $text = $num;
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
return $num;
```

Comment: That doesn't look "simple" to me. `$num = $text; do{$num = preg_replace('/.../','...',$num,-1,$c);} while($c);` would be easier. Still, I'm not sure that would solve the problem.

Comment: Using a regular expression for this is like using a sledgehammer to work on teeth. And `while(true)`. Really? Who upvoted this?

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty answer:
try to define all the params of number format, for what I know it should work.
At last, if nothign else works you don't need to use the regex, just juggle with the string version of your number:

```
function addCommas($number) {
    return strrev(join(",",str_split(strrev($number),3)));
}
```

After a short test session on codepad I can assure to you that you code should work as is,
at http://codepad.org/0zLuBQp8 you will find a slightly modified demo (I've retrieved data with a query and pasted the xml as string to circumvent some codepad limitations).

(I would suggest you to split the xml loading phase in two in order to check if your input is healty and you are manipulating the right datas)